# Python multiprocessing not reducing processing time much

Tags: python, django, python-multiprocessing

In my project I've implemented `python-multiprocessing` in order to have a increased processing speed. And I tested it in a 4 core system. But it shows only about 25% reduction in processing time.

**Here is a sample code:**

```
t1 = time.time()
p = Pool()
p.map(functin, file_list)
p.close()
p.join()
print '==========================================================='
print 'Pool put resume  took := ',time.time() - t1
print '==========================================================='
```

Theoratically there should be a 1\4th reduction in processing time since 4 cores are executing the function instead of single one. I also checked with task manager and confirmed that 4 processes are running.
So anyone please explain why it does not showing a significant reduction in processing time. Am i missing any configurations?

Comment: what is the difference between 25% and 1/4 processing reduction?

Comment: Suppose the process took 100sec normally is now completed in 75 seconds using multiprocessing.But theoratically it should be completed in 25 seconds.That what i meant@ShubhamNamdeo

Answer (score 1):

From the code you show I see that you apply some function to something called file_list, so it looks like in your function you work with files. In this case I would guess that your code is spending most time doing I/O, and its performance is limited by your hard drive speed, not by the number of cores.

Comment: So you are saying that multiprocessing wont make significant changes in file operations?

Comment: No, it won't. You cannot double the speed of hard drive just by reading two files at the same time, as disc operations are sequential on a physical level. Trying to do multiple files at the same time in case of HDD (not SSD) can actually make things slower in some cases because of seek time (reading head should be moved between different areas of disc).

Comment: What my function doing is it is reading the files to a tika server.So can you suggest a best way to reduce this operation time?

Comment: Yep, then nothing strange about the behavior you observe.

Comment: can you suggest a best way to reduce this operation time?

Comment: Except improving the hardware? It all depends on your exact situation, and there's no universal recipe here. I would guess that the best way is to have one process doing nothing but reading the files sequentially, and immediately dispatching the results to other worker process which are not doing any disc I/O, but don't hold your breath -- from what I understood about your situation, you probably will not be able to get even two times improvement. Disclaimer: I have no real experience with Apache Tika, so I'm not aware about any details which may arise from its usage.